# Jenkins Build periodically with parameters cron expression

Tags: cron, jenkins-pipeline

I only want to run once in a month, every 3rd Friday at 11 pm. I tried a cron expression “0 23 ? * FRI#3” in the Jenkinsfile. It shows a syntax error. What would be the correct expression?

```
        parameterizedCron('''
            0 23 ? * FRI#3 %INPUT-CHOICE=XXX; HOSTS=YYY
        ''')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure `FRI#3` is supported, but you can emulate that behavior with `0 23 15-21 * 5`

Translated: run at 23:00/11 PM (`0 23`), on a Friday (`5`), on the 15th up to and including the 21th (`15-21`) day of the month, each month (`*`). On the 15-21th day of each month only one Friday can occur; the 3rd Friday of the month.

Comment: Thanks for testing purposes I tried it doesn't work. No syntax errors though.
10 1 3-10 * 4 (2nd Thursday - today at 1:10 pm).

Comment: I tried with days range 8-14 as well.

Comment: Strange, have you ruled out input issues (spaces) and Timezone differences? See: https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-controllers/scheduled-job-builds-are-not-triggering-on-time

Comment: Yes, Jenkins validates immediately. Anyway, thanks.